# How to resolve IE9 X-domain AJAX errors?

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain, cors

## Having a problem with Ajax call in internet Explorer

I'm trying to make a ajax GET call X-domain, but its failing in IE9 (and I assume IE8).

```
$.ajax({
    url : '//testservice...',
    type : 'GET',
    data : { data: ...}
});
```

**Response:** *plaintext*

**Response Headers include:** `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

I'm Loading [jquery-xdomainrequest](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ajaxtransport-xdomainrequest/1.0.0/jquery.xdomainrequest.min.js)
as [described here](https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest) in an attempt to mitigate known IE xDomain cors issues.

#### Errors:

- `"No Transport"`
- `"Error: Access is denied."` *(when `jQuery.support.cors = true;`)*

Hitting the URL in the address bar directly (or in any other browser including IE10) gives the expected text response.

I've run out of things to try... Anything I missed? I unfortunately cannot change the server response (at least not without major effort).

### Edits

Currently running in IE9 proper; Browser/Document Mode: IE9

*without* `jQuery.support.cors = true;`

I recieve the "No Transport" error **with or without** the [jquery.xdomainrequest code](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ajaxtransport-xdomainrequest/1.0.0/jquery.xdomainrequest.min.js) added.

Hard-coding the protocol to `http://` doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: `crossDomain: true, // this doesn't seem to have any effect` it's not supposed to have any effect, it's true by default on cross-domain request. DO NOT use `jQuery.support.cors = true;`, then it definitely won't work. Make sure when you test with IE9 you're in IE9 mode, **jQuery does not support CORS requests in IE<9**

Comment: @KevinB Ah yes, [I see](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). I'll pull that out

Comment: "jQuery does not support CORS requests in IE<9": thus my attempted use of: [`jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest`](https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest)

Comment: My guess then is that the extension you added to add said support isn't working properly. I'll research what it's doing right quick.

Comment: Thanks Kevin! Please see the edit at the bottom of my question for some updated info.

Comment: Wait, is your url really `//testservice...`? the extension you added requires that it have http or https. I understand that gets translated to http or https, however the transport isn't written to handle that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32506/discussion-between-zach-l-and-kevin-b)